# ArangoDBs python docker

Tags: python, docker, arangodb

Using Docker, initialising ArangoDB from Python

Tried different ways to authenticate, always getting "error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified"

Not sure how to format / connect ArangoDB

```
import docker
client=docker.from_env()
img=client.images.pull("arangodb:latest")
[31]:

arangocommand="-e ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1"
​
db=client.containers.run(img,command=arangocommand)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ContainerError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-c5425f08f615> in <module>
      1 arangocommand="-e ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1"
      2 
----> 3 db=client.containers.run(img,command=arangocommand)

~/anaconda3/envs/dockerdb/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py in run(self, image, command, stdout, stderr, remove, **kwargs)
    793         if exit_status != 0:
    794             raise ContainerError(
--> 795                 container, exit_status, command, image, out
    796             )
    797 

ContainerError: Command '-e ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1' in image 'sha256:d41deeeb6f1189a07e3e567bd104c82b53350b67eaadbe044fae9c1158cd8c1c' returned non-zero exit status 1: b'error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified \n  You need to specify one of ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD, ARANGO_NO_AUTH and ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD\n
```

'

Looking for a simple and robust way to connect to ArangoDB in a Docker container from Python. How can I then continue using ArangoDB Docker from Python without having to think about that it is running in a Docker container. IE

> import dockerpy

then continuing to use only the dockerpy library

Answer (score 1):

According to `docker-py` [documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html), There is a parameter called `environment` which should takes care of the environment variables that should be passed inside the container while running it.

> environment (dict or list) – Environment variables to set inside the container, as a dictionary or a list of strings in the format ["SOMEVARIABLE=xxx"].

So you have to modify the script to the following:

```python
import docker

client=docker.from_env()

img=client.images.pull("arangodb:latest")
variables=["ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1"]
db=client.containers.run(img,environment=variables)
```

Then after executing it you can check the docker logs for the container which indicates that the container is up and running

```
automatically choosing storage engine
===========================================
GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
===========================================
...
2019-02-19T06:22:31Z [1] INFO using storage engine rocksdb
2019-02-19T06:22:31Z [1] INFO {cluster} Starting up with role SINGLE
...
2019-02-19T06:22:31Z [1] INFO {authentication} Authentication is turned on (system only), authentication for unix sockets is turned on
2019-02-19T06:22:32Z [1] INFO using endpoint 'http+tcp://0.0.0.0:8529' for non-encrypted requests
```

Regarding `command` paramter it is meant to be used in case you need to override the original `CMD` of the image while running a container.

> command (str or list) – The command to run in the container.